# Inverse properties

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we fave a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $\mathbb{E}\subseteq X$ where $\mathbb{E}$ is connected and there exist $A,B$ open sets such that
$f(\mathbb{E})\subseteq f(A)\cup f(B)$ and
$f(\mathbb{E})\cap f(A)\cap f(B)= \varnothing $

is it possible to do :$(f^{-1}f(\mathbb{E}))\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A)\cup f(B))\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))\cup f^{-1}(f(B))$

$f^{-1}(f(\mathbb{E}))\cap f^{-1}(f(A)\cap f(B))= \varnothing \Rightarrow $ $(\mathbb{E})\cap f^{-1}(f(A))\cap f^{-1}(f(B))=\varnothing$

i am trying to understand the proof that $f(\mathbb{E})$ is also connected and i just wonder why we didn't just do the above.I suppose that its not true but for what exactly reson is my question.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We suppose that
$$ f(E) = U_1 \cup U_2,$$
and
$$ U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset.$$
$U_1$ and $U_2$ are open sets of $Y.$
Then
$$f^{-1}(f(E))=f^{-1}(U_1) \cup f^{-1}(U_2),$$
and
$$E= f^{-1}(U_1) \cup f^{-1}(U_2).$$
$f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(U_1)$ and $f^{-1}(U_2)$ are open.
$E$ is connected. So
$f^{-1}(U_1)=E$ or $f^{-1}(U_2)=E.$
And because that
$$U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$$ we have
$$f^{-1}(U_1) \cap f^{-1}(u_2)=\emptyset$$  and consequently

$$f^{-1}(U_2) = \emptyset.$$
Hence $f(E)$ is connected.